# Radius Networks Android Ibeacon reference- can't get it to see a beacon

Tags: android, networking, ibeacon, radius

I'm trying to get the example Radius Network ibeacon reference app running on my Galaxy S3.
It does not error it just never sees any beacon in either activity or ranging mode.

There are no errors or warnings in eclipse.

The iBeacon locate app does work on the phone.

I'm using the classes.jar file which was in the AndroidIBeaconLibrary-0.7.6 archive and the android-ibeacon-reference-master.zip project.

I'm almost a total novice so not really sure where to look.

Any pointers to getting this working would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Your project is not properly configured.  You need more than the jar file for the library to work properly.  If you only take the jar file, you will not get the required service definitions in your AndroidManifest.xml.

See the [quick start guide](http://developer.radiusnetworks.com/ibeacon/android/configure.html) for full setup instructions.